# How to set the Image for facebook share dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, webforms

I set all my properties for the facebook share in the c# codebehind. However I am not having any luck with the Image, and I cannot find any solutions.

How I add the site name:

```
HtmlMeta siteNameProp = new HtmlMeta();
siteNameProp.Attributes.Add("property", "og:site_name");
siteNameProp.Content = "MyName";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(siteNameProp);
```

How I try to add the Image:

```
HtmlMeta imageProp = new HtmlMeta();
imageProp.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image");
imageProp.Content = "/Content/Images/FB-share.png";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(imageProp);
```

My Image size is 1200x630 (I read on SO that this size is recommended). And the Path to my Image is /Content/Images/FB-share.png.

No image is showing when I press share. What can I do? is the path wrong? Not that good with paths in c#.

Comment: og:image needs to be an absolute url. And if you share www.example.com you can't change the image for each person sharing that url. You can only have one image per url

Comment: Ah, where can I store the image? are there any good places?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug?

There is an Open Graph properties section to check if you set the image value correctly as `og:image`

You should also start using a lower resolution size than 1200 x 630 pixels: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

[EDIT]

There were some cases that Facebook randomly chooses a picture that has a lowest resolution size, so what I did is that I explicitly set the `og:image` value to the meta:

```
<meta id="featuredimage" runat="server" name="og:image" />
```

Then set the content value to my code-behind:

```
featuredimage.Attributes.Add("content", "image url here");
```

Happy coding!

Comment: I have and it works properly. But not the image. I do get this:
Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Comment: Your code does the exact same thing my does? However I also create the meta-tag in my codebehind. I add `og:image` as property and my image path to `content`

Comment: Can you please help me with the "Image url here" part? I think this is my problem. How do I link to an image that facebook scraper picks up? Say my Image is in `/Content/Images/FB-share.png` and my website name is `www.mywebsite.com`